# c++ custom compare function for std::sort()

Tags: c++

I want to create custom compare function for std::sort(), to sort some key-value pairs std::pair

Here is my function

```
 template <typename K, typename V>
 int comparePairs(const void* left, const void* right){
        if((((pair<K,V>*)left)->first) <= (((pair<K,V>*)right)->first))
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
```

Then, inside some class I have vector of pairs class member:

```
vector<pair<K,V>> items;
```

And some method for sort this vector by keys, using std::sort()

```
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), comparePairs<K,V>);
```

I have compilation errors within , which said

> "cannot convert parameter number from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const
>   void*'"

. What is a mistake?

Comment: Why are you taking your parameters as `void*`s? why not as `std::pair`s?

Comment: The mistake is that you are confusing the comparator to `std::sort` with one for `qsort`, which does require `const void *` arguments. Write a proper comparator for `std::sort` that accepts references to `pair<K, V>` and the problem will go away.

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this when it shows a complete lack of research, reading, paying attention, thinking, or anything else?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) already has the required comparison operators, which perform lexicographical comparisons using both elements of each pair. To use this, you just have to provide the comparison operators for types for types `K` and `V`.

Also bear in mind that `std::sort` requires a [*strict weak ordeing*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219005543/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) comparison, and `<=` does not satisfy that. You would need, for example, a less-than comparison `<` for `K` and `V`. With that in place, all you need is

```
std::vector<pair<K,V>> items; 
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end());
```

If you really need to provide your own comparison function, then you need something along the lines of

```
template <typename K, typename V>
bool comparePairs(const std::pair<K,V>& lhs, const std::pair<K,V>& rhs)
{
  return lhs.first < rhs.first;
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort.

It says:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

- **comp** - comparison function which returns ​*true* if the first argument is less than the second. The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following: `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`

Also, here's an example of how you can use `std::sort` using a custom C++14 polymorphic lambda:

```
std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container),
          [] (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Your comparison function is not even wrong.

Its arguments should be the type stored in the range, i.e. `std::pair<K,V>`, not `const void*`.

It should return `bool` not a positive or negative value. Both `(bool)1` and `(bool)-1` are `true` so your function says **every** object is ordered before **every other** object, which is clearly impossible.

You need to model the less-than operator, not `strcmp` or `memcmp` style comparisons.

See [StrictWeakOrdering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) which describes the properties the function must meet.