# Sort by using an integer number in C++ (custom usage of std::sort)

Tags: c++, sorting

I want a list of strings sorted first by a number, and if the number is equal to 0, then sort it alphabetically.

Let's say I have :

```
struct numberedString{
     string s;
     int n;
}
```

I have an array `numberedString a[]` how do I sort the entries in the array using `std::sort()`? I think I first need to sort all the `numberedString.s` and then sort by the `numberedString.n`, but I don't see how exactly to do this ?

Comment: Start by writing a function that takes two `const struct numberedString&`s and returns whether the first is less than the second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ custom compare function for std::sort()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894700/c-custom-compare-function-for-stdsort)

Comment: "I want a list of string sorted by a number" - can you clarify what that even means?

Answer (score 1):

Ask and you shall receive.  Here you go.

### Case 1: Specialized function object - functor.

```
struct functor
{
  bool operator() (const numberedString& a,
                   const numberedString& b)
  {
    if ((a.n != 0) && (b.n != 0))
    {
       return a.n < b.n;
    }
    return a.s < b.s;
  }
};
```

### Case 2: Overloading operator < in structure.

```
struct numberedString
{
  string s;
  int n;
  bool operator<(const numberedString& other) const
  {
    if ((n != 0) && (other.n != 0))
    {
       return n < other.n;
    }
    return s < other.s;
  }
};
```

Usage:
Overloading the `operator<` allows functions to compare instances of your structure naturally:

```
  numberedString c, d;
  if (c < d)
  {
    cout << "c < d\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "c >= d\n";
  }
```

The functor allows you to pass a comparison algorithm to ordering functions like `std::sort`:

```
   numberedString array[25];
   std::sort(&array[0], &array[25], functor);
```

*Note:  See std::sort for exact syntax.*

**BTW, what are the rules for when one variable has a number of zero and the other doesn't?**

Comment: Out-of-class `operator<` is preferred. The same for other comparison operators. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Basically all the values with a `n!=0` are to be sorted numericaly within themsleves and the values where `n==0`are to be sorted alphabetically within themselves. At the end , all the values where `n!=0` are first then the others , all sorted

Answer (score -1):

Basically your structure is so trivial that you could replace it with a `std::pair`.

```
using numberedString = std::pair<int, std::string>;
```

Then you could just use `std::sort` in the ordinary way and due to the `std::pair` lexicographical compare, you'll get you're desired effect, simple and without defining a custom comparator (example below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using numberedString = std::pair<int, std::string>;

int main() {
  numberedString vec1[] = {{4, "four"}, {2, "two"}, {1, "one"}};
  std::sort(std::begin(vec1), std::end(vec1));
  for(auto &&i : vec1) std::cout << i.first << " -- " << i.second << '\n';
  std::cout << std::endl;

  numberedString vec2[] = {{0, "four"}, {0, "two"}, {0, "one"}};
  std::sort(std::begin(vec2), std::end(vec2));
  for(auto &&i : vec2) std::cout << i.first << " -- " << i.second << '\n';
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27d65e9fb512049c)

Comment: I guess the same reason why my answer was downvoted... We both read the question wrong. He wants to sort by the string only if the integers are both zero, not if they are equal. This is not a classical two-criteria-sorting which you solve with pairs (and me with tuples).

Comment: @leemes `He wants to sort by the string only if the integers are both zero` and so my code will.

Comment: No, you also sort by the string if the integers are not zero but equal. Like `{{1, "z"}, {1, "a"}}` should be unchanged, but your code swaps the items. Your examples just don't cover this case ;)

Comment: @leemes where the OP says that?

Comment: He wrote "sorted first by a number, and if the number is equal to 0, then sort it alphabetically." -- That means, if the number is not equal to 0, it shouldn't be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @leemes "If the number is not equal to 0, it shouldn't be sorted alphabetically." this is nowhere in the OP's question.

Comment: I didn't quote it. But I understand it like that, since he doesn't say what to do if it isn't equal to 0. He **only** wants to sort it alphabetically **if** it equals 0. You **always** sort it alphabetically if the numbers of the two objects are equal, which is also not mentioned in the question. It is indeed misleading, but your answer currently is wrong, so was mine. However I doubt that the OP actually wanted to say this (but he did). Anyways, I don't want to argue with you. I never said I downvoted your answer, by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89109/discussion-between-101010-and-leemes).