# Is there any prerequisite for compare function that we pass to sort algorithm in c++ STL?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

struct PAIR { int first; int second; };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PAIR& rec)
{
    os << "(" << rec.first << ", " << rec.second << ")";
    return os;
}

bool fun(const PAIR& x, const PAIR& y) { return x.first < y.first; }

int main()
{
    vector<PAIR > v{ {1,3},{2,3}, {1,0}, {1,5} };
    auto x1 = v;
    cout << "v: ";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator< PAIR >(cout, ", "));
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "sorting now\n";
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), fun);
    cout << "v: ";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator< PAIR >(cout, ", "));
    cout << "\n";
}
```

output:
v: (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 0), (1, 5),
sorting now
v: (1, 3), (1, 0), (1, 5), (2, 3),

Changing `bool fun(const PAIR& x, const PAIR& y) { return x.first < y.first; }`  to `bool fun(const PAIR& x, const PAIR& y) { return x.first <= y.first; }` is failing during runtime.

I have just changed < to <= in function fun().  Looks like there is some prerequisite for comparison function that we pass to STL sort algorithm.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing during runtime"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ custom compare function for std::sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894700/c-custom-compare-function-for-stdsort)

Comment: Your function does not impose a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), as is required.

Comment: @UnholySheep I am using Visual Studio. Program is crashing with the following error. 'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\pc\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
.... 
The thread 0x4f08 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: There's no mention of any crash or other exception in that output you copied

Comment: @JohnFilleau  Thank you very much.   Two objects x and y are equivalent if both f(x, y) and f(y, x) are false. Note that an object is always (by the irreflexivity invariant) equivalent to itself.  Compare function f must satisfy the following.
Irreflexivity f(x, x) must be false. My function fails here itself.
Antisymmetry f(x, y) implies !f(y, x)
Transitivity f(x, y) and f(y, z) imply f(x, z).

Comment: Just a style note: any reason you defined `fun` rather than simply overloading `operator<` for two `const PAIR&`?

Comment: @UnholySheep Program:  I have just started with Visual studio. Upon checking it well I see the following. ...ource\repos\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\xutility
Line: 632

Expression: invalid comparator

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

Comment: @Chris  I wanted to see how stable_sort behaves if I give my own comparator. My doubt was how stable_sort will know two values are same. All I was giving is one comparator function.  I thought If I give <= it would swap without preserving order. But in my case before trying out stable_sort , sort itself has failed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any prerequisite for compare function that we pass to sort algorithm in c++ STL?

Yes. It must satisfy the requirements of the `Compare` concept.

> I have just changed < to <= in function fun().

After that change, the function doesn't satisfy the requirements of `Compare` concept, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: [C++ named requirement: Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

Comment: Is this really a (C++20) concept?

Comment: @fabian I always call them concepts when I bring them up in casual conversation (I'm fun at parties) because they are concepts in the vernacular. I don't think it's a `concept`. Just a *concept*.

Comment: @fabian  It is old concept. Not newly introduced in C++20.

Comment: @JohnFilleau  Thank you very much. Your link clarified my doubt.